# Python list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing

I just can't understand why my list is out of range.

I've been stuck on this problem forever now and can't wrap my head around what the problem might be.

Obviously I'm new into programming.

```
def list(self,filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as listTeams:
        teamCount = 0
        indexList = []
        unsortedList = []
        lines = listTeams.readlines()

        for line in open(filename):
            teamCount += 1

        listTeams.seek(0)

        for i in range(0, teamCount):
            tempStr = listTeams.readlines(i)
            tempStr = "".join(tempStr)
            indexList = tempStr.split(" ")
            for i in range(0,i):
                print(i)
                unsortedList[i] = Team(indexList[0], indexList[1], indexList[2], indexList[3], indexList[4], indexList[5], indexList[6])
                print(unsortedList[i])
    return
```

I get this error message:

```
unsortedList[i] = Team(indexList[0], indexList[1], indexList[2], indexList[3], indexList[4], indexList[5], indexList[6])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: How many columns are there in the file? `indexList[6]` requires every line to have at least 7 fields.

Comment: unsortedList = [] just creates an unsized list. It looks like you want to use .append(Team(...)) instead.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I would *really* not recommend naming a function `list`, since that is a built-in function in python.

Comment: Why are you using `listTeams.readlines(i)` to read each line? You already read them all into the list `lines`. You can just do `for tempStr in lines`.

Comment: You can also do `teamCount = len(lines)`, you don't need to read the file again and count the lines.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! .append did the job. I do agree that list is not a good name for a function that was not in my mind at all. will change. i also changed the code accordingly to Barmar's comment

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign values to List items which don't exist. You can use one of the two methods to solve this problem.
One, you can use this command unsortedList.append(Team(indexList[0], indexList[1], indexList[2]).
or 
Second, you can create a list apriori which contains as many zeros as your list will contain by using the command unsortedList= numpy.zeros(i), it will create a list with i number of zeros then you can replace those zeros using your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can't assign to a list element that doesn't already exist, you can use append method

```
unsortedList.append(Team(indexList[0], indexList[1], indexList[2], indexList[3], indexList[4], indexList[5], indexList[6]))
```

also check the how many items in the array before accessing by index len(indexList) give you the number of items in the array, check that is more than 6 before you get the items 0 to 6 in the `indexList`